# Minimization of the asymptotic variance in MCMC

Tags: variance, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, asymptotics, metropolis-hastings

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a Markov chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Assume $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is stationary and consider the ergodic averages $$A_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)$$ for some a priori fixed square-integrable $f$. Assume our goal is to minimize the asymptotic variance $$\sigma^2:=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\operatorname{Var}[A_n].$$

> Tierney's theorem (see, for example, [[1, Theorem 4]](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoap/1027961031), [[2, Theorem 2.7]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06197.pdf) and [[3, Lemma 2]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228341643_Covariance_ordering_for_discrete_and_continuous_time_Markov_chains)) gives us a guideline how the transition kernel $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ influences $\sigma^2$ - either in terms of nonnegative operators (in [1] and [2]) or the inverse Laplacian (in [3]).
>
> However, [1] and [2] give a condition under which the asymptotic variance of *every* $f$ would be minimized and the corresponding minimization problem is complicated, since it depends on this additional parameter. So, my question is: Is there any easier condition on the transition kernel, depending solely on our fixed $f$, which ensures that $\sigma^2$ is minimized? [3] might be such a condition, but it involves the computation of the inverse Laplacian (which has no easy to handle closed form; does it?).

Comment: Which set of kernels do you consider for the minimisation?

Comment: @Xi'an I've asked for the concrete application here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/343651/91890.