# Central limit theorem for a Metropolis-Hastings estimator

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

Let $\alpha$ denote the acceptance function of the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and target distribution $\mu$$^1$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ denote the corresponding proposal sequence. Now let $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and consider the estimator $$A_nf:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n((1-\alpha(X_{i-1},Y_i))f(X_{i-1})+\alpha(X_{i-1},Y_i)f(Y_i))\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ of $\mu f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$.

> Are we able to prove a central limit theorem $$\sqrt n(A_nf-\mu f)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathcal N_{0,\:\sigma^2(f)}\tag1$$ in distribution? If so, can we give a closed form expression for $\sigma^2(f)$? In particular, will $$n\operatorname{Var}[A_nf]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sigma^2(f)\tag2$$ hold?

Note that $$Z_n:=(X_{n-1},Y_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ is again a time-homogeeous Markov chain with transition kernel $$\kappa_{\text{aug}}((x,y),A\times B):=1_A(x)(1-\alpha(x,y))Q(x,B)+1_A(y)\alpha(x,y)Q(y,B)$$ for $x,y\in E$ and $A,B\in\mathcal E$ and stationary distribution $\nu:=\mu\otimes Q$. (In general, $\nu$ is *not* reversible with respect to $\kappa_{\text{aug}}$. Are we able to show the reversibility under the assumption that $q$ is symmetric? If you know the answer, please take a look at my corresponding separate question: [Is the stationary distribution of the augmented Metropolis-Hastings kernel even reversible in the symmetric proposal case?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/432478/222528).)

*Remark*: Note that the paper [On a Metropolis-Hastings importance sampling estimator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf) contains a related result in Theorem 15 (cf. Theorem 4).

---

$^1$ To be precise, let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space;
- $p$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $\mu:=p\lambda$;
- $q:E^2\to[0,\infty)$ be ${\mathcal E}^{\otimes2}$-measurable with $$\int\lambda({\rm d}y)q(x,y)=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E$$ and $$Q(x,\;\cdot\;):=q(x,\;\cdot\;)\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E;$$
- $$\alpha(x,y):=\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle1\wedge\frac{p(y)q(y,x)}{p(x)q(x,y)}&\text{, if }p(x)q(x,y)\ne0\\1&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E$$ and $$\kappa(x,B):=\int_BQ(x,{\rm d}y)\alpha(x,y)+\left(1-\int Q(x,{\rm d}y)\alpha(x,y)\right)1_B(x)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since
$$[\{1-\alpha(X_{i-1},Y_i)\}f(X_{i-1})+\alpha(X_{i-1},Y_i)f(Y_i)]= \overbrace{\mathbb E[f(X_i)|X_{i-1},Y_i]}^\text{integrating out $U_i$}=H(X_{i-1},Y_i)$$
the sum$$A_nf=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n H(X_{i-1},Y_i)$$satisfies the standard ergodic theorem for the Markov chain $(X_{i-1},Y_i)$ and under geometric ergodicity satsfies a Central Limit theorem with asymptotic variance
$$\text{var}(\mathbb E[f(X_2)|X_{1},Y_2])+2\sum_{t=1}^\infty \text{cov}(\mathbb E[f(X_2)|X_{1},Y_2],\mathbb E[f(X_{t+2})|X_{t+1},Y_{t+2}])$$

Comment: Ah, I see. If we define $$H((x,y),\;\cdot\;):=(1-\alpha(x,y))\delta_{(x,\:y)}+\alpha(x,y)\delta_{(y,\:x)},$$ then $\operatorname E\left[f(X_n)\mid Z_n\right]=(H\tilde f)(Z_n)$, where $\tilde f(x,y):=f(x)$. Note that, while I know what it should be, there is no $U_i$ in the question. So, your answer might be hard to understand for someone else.

Comment: Can we simplify your expression for the asymptotic variance? We may note that $\nu$ is reversible with respect to $H$ (the $H$ from my comment above). I know that if $g\in L^2(\nu)$ is a solution of $(1-\kappa_{\text{aug}})g=h$, where $h=H\tilde f$, then the asymptotic variance is given by $2\operatorname{Cov}_\nu[g,h]-\operatorname{Var}_\nu[h]$. This could be use to perform a worst case analysis, but I've got the feeling that things are easier here for our special choice of $h$.

Comment: Could you give a reference for the standard ergodic theorem? I'm not sure which assumption we need to impose on $f$. Oh, and it would be great if you could reply to my last comment. As you might imagine, I'm still trying to solve [my other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/429318/222528), but with the estimator there replaced with the one from this question. My hope is that the expression for the asymptotic variance of this estimator is easier to minimize than the other one. Unfortunately, the series representation is not very handy.

Comment: I'll answer some of my questions by myself: (a) I guess it's just a typo in your answer, but it seems like your indices are off by $1$. The asymptotic variance should be $$\sigma^2(f):=\operatorname{Var}\left[\operatorname E\left[f_0(X_1)\mid Z_1\right]\right]+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{Cov}\left[\operatorname E\left[f_0(X_1)\mid Z_1\right],\operatorname E\left[f_0(X_{1+n})\mid Z_{1+n}\right]\right],$$ where (for further reference) $f_0:=f-\mu f.$

Comment: (b) Assuming $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is stationary, we should have $$\sigma^2(f)=\operatorname{Var}_\nu[g_0]+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{Cov}_\nu\left[\kappa^n_{\text{aug}}g_0,g_0\right],$$ where $g_0:=H\tilde f_0$ and $\tilde f_0(x,y):=f_0(x)$ for $x,y\in E$.

Comment: (c) We may note that $\nu g_0=\nu\tilde f_0=\mu f_0=0$. Moreover, for arbitrary $g_0\in L^2(\nu)$ with $\nu g_0=0$ such that $Gg_0:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\kappa_{\text{aug}}^ng_0$ exists, $n\operatorname{Var}\left[B_ng_0\right]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sigma^2(g_0),$ where $$B_ng_0:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ng_0(Z_i)$$ (the reason is that $(1-\kappa_{\text{aug}})^{-1}g_0=Gg_0$). For our special choice of $g_0$, $Bng_0=A_nf_0=A_nf$. Is there an easy criterion on $f$ ensuring that $Gg_0$ exists or should I search for a more general criterion on the existence of the asymptotic variance?

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but how is the $H$ in your answer defined?

Comment: The previous line only contains the word "since" ... I guess $H$ needs to be some kind of regular version of $\mathbb E[f(X_i)|X_{i-1},Y_i]$, but I don't get then why $H$ doesn't depend on $i$.